# Another Delphi to Java porting issue

Tags: java, delphi, binary, porting

I'm porting an old application written in Delphi to Java. 
I'm having some trouble with this function, that calculates the CRC of a transmitted message.

Here's the original code:

```
       if(ReceivedMessage[slot].Message[1] = $FD) and
          (ReceivedMessage[slot].MessageLength in [1..16]) and
          (ReceivedMessage[slot].Message[counter] = $FF) then
       begin
        index := 2;
        ReceivedMessage[slot].DataReady := TRUE;

        for counter := 1 to ReceivedMessage[slot].MessageLength do
        begin
          Inc(index);

          if ReceivedMessage[slot].Message[index] < $F8 then
            ReceivedMessage[slot].Data[counter] := ReceivedMessage[slot].Message[index]
          else
          if ReceivedMessage[slot].Message[index] = $F8 then
          begin
            Inc(index);

            ReceivedMessage[slot].Data[counter] := ReceivedMessage[slot].Message[index] or $F0;
          end
          else
            ReceivedMessage[slot].DataReady := FALSE;  // Invalid data
        end;

        if ReceivedMessage[slot].DataReady = TRUE then
        begin
          Inc(index);

          if ReceivedMessage[slot].Message[index] < $F8 then
            ReceivedMessage[slot].CRC := ReceivedMessage[slot].Message[index] shl 8
          else
          if ReceivedMessage[slot].Message[index] = $F8 then
          begin
            Inc(index);

            ReceivedMessage[slot].CRC := (ReceivedMessage[slot].Message[index] or $F0) shl 8;
          end;

          Inc(index);

          if ReceivedMessage[slot].Message[index] < $F8 then
            ReceivedMessage[slot].CRC := ReceivedMessage[slot].CRC or ReceivedMessage[slot].Message[index]
          else
          if ReceivedMessage[slot].Message[index] = $F8 then
          begin
            Inc(index);

            ReceivedMessage[slot].CRC := ReceivedMessage[slot].CRC or        ReceivedMessage[slot].Message[index] or $F0;
          end;
```

And here's my Java code:

```
 if(array[1]==0xFD && (array[2]>0 && array[2]<17) && array[pos]==(byte)0xFF)
 {
index=2;
for(int counter=1;counter<splMsg.nbytes+1;counter++)
{
     index++;
 if(array[index]<0xF8)
     data[counter]=array[index];
 else
     if(array[index]==0xF8)
     {
      index++;
      data[counter]=(byte)(array[index] | 0xF0);
     }
     else
         return 0xFC; 
}


index++;
short crc=0x0000;

if(array[index]<0xF8)
     crc=(short) (array[index]<<8);
else
   if(array[index]==0xF8)
   {
    index++;
    crc=(short)((array[index] | 0xF0) << 8);
   }
index++;
if(array[index]<0xF8)
    crc=(short) (crc | array[index]);
else
   if(array[index]==0xF8)
   {
    index++;
    crc=(short)(crc | array[index] | 0xF0);
   }

msgcrc=new byte[] {(byte)(crc >> 8 & 0xff),(byte)(crc & 0xff)};
```

My function return the transmitted CRC code most times, but sometimes fails and returns the last two bytes of the message. The last 3 bytes of the message are the CRC code (2 byte) and the end-of-message 0xff byte.

Any help?

Thanks,
Pedro

Comment: Is 'array' of type `byte`?

Comment: Hi Neet, no, array is a byte[]

Comment: @Pedro Can you think of a more descriptive title for your question other than `Another Delphi to Java porting issue`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remember:

Java byte is *signed*. So:

```
byte test = (byte)255;
System.out.println(test);
```

will output: `-1`

and

```
    byte test = (byte)255;
    System.out.println(test == 255);
```

will print `false`, but

```
    byte test = (byte)255;
    System.out.println((test & 255) == 255);
```

will do what I think you want to achieve (in this case prints `true`).

To get unsigned (byte) values use `(array[index] & 255)`.

You will have to do the masking with 0xff everywhere, otherwise you will get sign extended integers for byte  values larger than 127.

For compares you can also always do a cast to `byte` (e.g. `if(test == (byte)255)`) but I think one should stick to a single conversion, so I would recommend going with the `& 0xff` masking.

Comment: Thanks, Neet. I've added the mask to every array[index] and it worked!